# import built from source libraries to python

Tags: python, c++, libraries

I built from source OpenCV library using cmake and visual studio 2019
the modules of the library were generated mainly on 3 different types of files such:  **.hpp .lib .dll** extensions. everything worked well for c++ projects and the library was successfully imported. **the issue now is to import that to Python**. the question is what to do next which files has to be intergrated to python and how?

Comment: You need to write bindings, see this: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html

Comment: excuse my long comment I have already crossed this in fact this is video documented [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9q-LHP7cMfg&t=238s), in my case the project building generated a huge directory (and subfolders) full with hpp header couldnt include them in the c++ file. I feel like I have everything the libs the dlls the hpps but cannot run this in python. actually I know the main reason I just couldn't  **build the .pyd file** I am struggling trying this since 8 days now I followed many tutorials  asked 3 desperate question in stackoverflow  the cv2.pyd is simply always not there